# How to understand re.split(r'(\w)+', 'test abcd')

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Why is only the last letter on the list?

```
>>> re.split(r'(\w)+', 'test abcd')
['', 't', ' ', 'd', '']
```

If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible.

Comment: Because you use `\w` you can try : `r'(\w+)+'`

Comment: You want the result to be `['test', 'abcd']`? Then you should use `r'(\w+)'` so the quantifier is within the capture group

Comment: @Cory Kramer I do not want any output. I just wonder how the function works.

Comment: Because you are saying capture one character, and so it matches and captures them each in turn, but it can only return one, so it returns the last one. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: If you check on regex101 the answer is right there: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

Comment: Please read the question carefully: This is not matching, but `split`ting.